# curl doesn't send all content on PUT with -d

Tags: http, curl

I have the problem, that curl doesn't upload all my data, when uploading with `-d @-`

The following command doesn't work:
`tar -cz folder | curl -X PUT -d @- http://example.com/api/take/file`

The following command works:
`tar -cz folder | curl -X PUT -T - http://example.com/api/take/file`

Does somebody know what is the reason for this behaviour.

Comment: I'd inspect the request header fields; maybe one variant uses gzip encoding and your server doesn't handle it?

Comment: the header fields are the same, except the Content-Length. In the case with -d @- already the Content-Length Header in the Request has the wrong number (size).

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the root cause in the docs of curl:

```
--data-ascii <data>

(HTTP) This is just an alias for -d, --data.
```

So when you use just `-d` then the data will sent as ascii.
According to the docs binary data should be sent with `--data-binary` and indeed the following command works
`tar -cz folder | curl -X PUT --data-binary @- http://example.com/api/take/file`